# Can I customize app bars on each destinations in a bottom navigation bar?

Tags: consistency, toolbar

I am designing an Android app with 5 destinations in the bottom navigation bar. The main screen is one of them. It's a list of events and the app bar there is pretty custom - prominent with the logo, search icon, sort and a dropdown to choose a city. In other destinations I have just the regular app bar with the logo or the screen title and a "join" icon for example.

One of the destinations in the nav bar is a list of contests that the user can take a part in. This is actually the main feature in the app. The currency is points, so the user needs to know the point balance.

This is where I have the problem. I don't think I can squeeze the balance into app bars in all of the destinations - they are already full. So I was wondering if showing it only on the contest destination could be a good idea (or not - because it would not be consistent across the app). The other situation when user can take a part in a contest is from a particular event screen, so there they would not know the balance and therefore if they can afford to pay for the contest.

I kind of feel like the user should be aware of the balance at all times, but I am not 100% sure, I need to make a decision by myself (with no users) and I have no idea how to squeeze the balance value on other app bars or if it's absolutely necessary.

I attach the main screen for visualization some of the app bars that I already have in the app.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be two questions, so I will try to address both of them.

### You can safely customize the app bar on respective tabs

Generally, the user perception of different tabs equals to different parts of the app. It might not be consistent, but it is pretty common and users are quite used to it. It helps you to tailor the UX for the specific tasks. Keeping it consistent might be a good systematic thinking, but it could hurt the UX which I consider to be more important in this case.

#### Nondirect question - Should the points be presented at all times?

It seems like the problem with your navigation boils down to the currency being present in the navigation at all times. Unless you can spend the currency on all the views, it is not necessary. I would put the currency only on views where you can actually interact with it or spend it.